# Method setText() must be called from the UI Thread, currently inferred thread is worker thread

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm making a project in Android Studio, and somewhere i've to use AsyncTask, but when i try to setText in a try catch i got the error: "Method setText() must be called from the UI Thread, currently inferred thread is worker"
What to do?
Here's some prints of my code:

[onCreate and onClick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do7OV.png)

[Validate user on AsyncTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrqDq.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Ok, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

That error is expected if you're trying to update any UI components on a separate thread. I have myself a helper function that I use to run specific things back on the UI thread, here's the important bits:

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
    public void run() {
        txt_Error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think i didn't understood your answer friend. How that solves my problem?

Comment: You need to run `setText` back on the UI thread (which is your error). One of the ways to do this is to use a `Handler` as I've indicated above that uses the Main UI Thead(`getMainLooper()`). I've added the `setText` code from your snapshot over at my answer.

Comment: One more question: That code of yours replaces my catch?

Answer (score 0):

The error says you can't call `txt_Error.setText()` method there because the AsyncTask **DoInBackGround** runs in the background, in other words, the `txt_Error.setText()` method can just be called from the IU thread.

What you can do is to call this method `publishProgress(2 parameter);` in the **DoInBackground** and add this method `onProgressUpdate(2 parameter)` in the AsyncTask pressing **ALT + O**.

The `onProgressUpdate(2 parameter)` method runs in the Main Thread or IU Thread, so every time you call `publishProgress(2 parameter);` in the **DoInBackground** the `onProgressUpdate()` is triggered.

Another important thing is, the `publishProgress(2 parameter);` method send and  `onProgressUpdate(2 parameter)` method recive the second parameter you established at the beginning `private class validateUserTask extends AsyncTask <1 parameter, 2 parameter, 3 parameter>`.

Example:

```
            new AsyncTask<Integer,String,Void>(){

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

                       *can call this method wherever you want here*

                        publishProgress(string);


                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... values) {

                            text.setText(values[0]);
                }

            }.execute();
```

Note: I just did the AsyncTask in a method... (easier)

Comment: I'll use AsyncTask for other purpose friend, but many thanks for your kindly help!